# Radio Button grouping in the multi column list view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, radio-button

I have a list view with 3 following columns:
1. a Text Column
2. Radio button
3. Radio button

I am trying to group the two radio Button but all the radio button gets in one group.
e.g. if there are two listview items (two rows), then all the 4 radio button gets grouped as one.

```
<ListView Name="ruleListView"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
 Margin="10">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </Style>
                        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <GridViewColumn 
                                Header="Rule"

                                >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Width="410"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Rule}" TextAlignment="Left"
                                        />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn 
                                Header="Configuration Key"
                            Width="140"

                                >

                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton GroupName="Rule"
                                                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn 
                                Header="Event"
                                Width="100"
                                >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton GroupName="Rule"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                 IsChecked="True"
                                                 />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

I expect that grouping should be done as per the particular row.

Comment: Using the same GroupName is forcing all the radio buttons to be linked together. Depending on what objects you're binding to in the list, you can accomplish what you want using data bindings.

Comment: Two radio buttons are independent of the item source binds to the list. can you please explain more what are you suggesting?

Comment: I can explain more, but I need to know if you are using MVVM and binding objects to the ItemSource or if you are manually setting the the items directly in the UI? If you are binding objects to the ItemSource, are you binding custom objects which you are able to modify the source code?

Comment: As of now, I am not using MVVM for the item source.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the RadioButton.GroupName applies to all active controls. That is why you are seeing all the radio buttons linked together. In order to get each row to be linked you need a unique GroupName for each row. In MVVM you could bind the GroupName to a property on the underlying item, or bind the RadioButton's IsChecked property to the ViewModel and manage the switching in code.

Since your not using ViewModels it is a little more complicated. You still need to create a unique GroupName per row. The easiest way I can think of to do this is to use a IValueConverter to get the row index.

```
public class RadioGroupIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ListViewItem lvi)
        {
            var listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(lvi);
            var index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lvi);
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", parameter, index);
        }
        return parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to bind to the GroupName to the ListViewItem using the converter.

First you need to add the converter as a resources in xaml. Where <converters: is a reference to the namespace of the RadioGroupIndexConverter class. If you created the class in the same namespace as your ListView you can just use <local:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <converters:RadioGroupIndexConverter x:Key="GroupConverter"/>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then you'll change your RadioButton.GroupName to use a relative binding.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource GroupConverter}}"/>
```